# I want to upload a video from my web page to youtube by using javascript youtube API

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube-javascript-api

I want to upload a video from my web page to youtube by using javascript youtube API but there  is coming "User authentication required", error 401.

Can anyone help me with some demo example in javascript, which can upload a video on youtube from my web page?

Answer (score 1):

Google has posted several demo examples in JavaScript of uploading a video to using the YouTube API:

- http://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git%2Fyt-upload-javascript
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Is that what you were looking for?