# How to upload a video to youtube using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, upload, youtube-api, html5-video

I want to upload a video to youtube using javascript. Currently， I can login and get the list of the videos, but I do not know how to write the snippet to upload files.

I used google js api [Link1](https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady)
and youtube v3 api [Link2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

```
var requestOptions = {
playlistId: playlistId,
part: 'snippet',
myRating:'like',
maxResults: 1
};
var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.insert(requestOptions);
```

I am using the above code to get video list items, but not sure how to continue to upload a video.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683240/i-want-to-upload-a-video-from-my-web-page-to-youtube-by-using-javascript-youtube ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit]
CORS is supported now in v3 and here's latest answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19691307/1973552

Right now there is a problem on v3 due to CORS. For now you can use v2 if Javascript implementation is urgent.
[Here's an example](http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html).

On the other hand, we are hoping to get v3 fixed really soon for Javascript uploads and that will be the long term solution.

Comment: can you tell me what is the problem of v3. I find firefox works on CORS as XMLHttpRequest and for IE, it has XDomainRequest object. So, I think it should not be a problem.

Comment: It's on the YouTube side. https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4050