# How do I upload directly to YouTube without uploading to server first?

Tags: php, file-upload, youtube-api, google-api, google-api-php-client

I have tested and used Google's [resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads) code sample. Based on that, if I use HTML5's upload file API, I would have to upload the file to the server first then post the video's name to Google's resumable upload php file, right? If so, then this would mean a very long upload process because I'm uploading to two servers consecutively.

Hence, my question title. Is it possible? If so, please point me to the right direction or simple tutorials using YouTube API v3 to get started. Thank you very much!

P.s. I've heard of Zend Framework but I don't want to install the whole thing just to use a simple YouTube upload. Please guide me by extending the usage from Google's code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible approaches right now.

1. Browser based upload via YouTube API v2 (scheduled to be removed april 2015)
   https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading
2. CORS upload with API v3.
   [SO Question with details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690545/youtube-api-v3-0-browser-based-uploading-in-php/19691307#19691307)

Comment: I knew about no.2 shortly after I posted this question but was unable to answer my own question right-away due to SO's rules and hence, forgotten to follow-up. Thanks for the additional info of no.1, btw!