# Will there be browser based uploads in v3 YouTubeApi?

Tags: youtube-api

Will there be browser based uploads in v3?  In v2 we can upload directly from a browser and bypass the server but there hasn't been any news about the same feature for v3.  Thanks

Comment: Check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19691307/1973552