# How do I upload a video to Youtube directly from my server?

Tags: api, oauth, youtube

I'm setting up a (headless) web server that lets people build their own custom time-lapse movies.

Several people want to upload the time-lapse videos they make to YouTube.
Rather than download the video to that person's laptop,
and the that person manually uploads it to YouTube,
is there a way I can write some software on my web server to take that video file on my web server and upload it directly to that user's account on YouTube?

I've been told that asking my users for their YouTube handle and password is the Wrong Thing To Do, and I should be using the YouTube V3 API with Oauth.

I tried the techniques listed at
" [I want to upload a video from my web page to youtube by using javascript youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683240/i-want-to-upload-a-video-from-my-web-page-to-youtube-by-using-javascript-youtube) ",
which seems to "work", but every time I had to download the video to that person's laptop and then uploading from the laptop to YouTube. Is there a way to tweak that system to upload directly from my server to YouTube?

I found some python code that (after I set up my client_secrets.json) lets me upload videos directly from my server directly to someone's YouTube account *after* that person did the Oauth authentication.
But the first time some new person tries to upload a video to some new YouTube account that my server has never dealt with before, it either
(a) pops open a web browser on my server, and then if I VNC to the server and type in a YouTube handle and password into that web browser, it gets authenticated -- but I'd rather not do that for every user.
(b) with the "--noauth_local_webserver" option, spits out a URL on the command line and waits. Then if I manually copy that URL and paste it into a web browser, log in to YouTube, copy-and-paste the token back into this application that is still waiting for input on the command line, that person gets authenticated. But I'd rather not do that for every user. I guess that would be OK if I could capture that URL in my cgi-bin script and stick it in a web page, and then later somehow get the authentication response and cram it back into this program, but how? I don't even see that print statement or the raw_input statement in this code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#upload_a_video
# which is identical to the code sample at
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

import httplib
import httplib2
import os
import random
import sys
import time

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow


# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, httplib.NotConnected,
  httplib.IncompleteRead, httplib.ImproperConnectionState,
  httplib.CannotSendRequest, httplib.CannotSendHeader,
  httplib.ResponseNotReady, httplib.BadStatusLine)

# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]

# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google Developers Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
# authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES = ("public", "private", "unlisted")


def get_authenticated_service(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

  return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
  tags = None
  if options.keywords:
    tags = options.keywords.split(",")

  body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title=options.title,
      description=options.description,
      tags=tags,
      categoryId=options.category
    ),
    status=dict(
      privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
    )
  )

  # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
  insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part=",".join(body.keys()),
    body=body,
    # The chunksize parameter specifies the size of each chunk of data, in
    # bytes, that will be uploaded at a time. Set a higher value for
    # reliable connections as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    # value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    #
    # Setting "chunksize" equal to -1 in the code below means that the entire
    # file will be uploaded in a single HTTP request. (If the upload fails,
    # it will still be retried where it left off.) This is usually a best
    # practice, but if you're using Python older than 2.6 or if you're
    # running on App Engine, you should set the chunksize to something like
    # 1024 * 1024 (1 megabyte).
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
  )

  resumable_upload(insert_request)

# This method implements an exponential backoff strategy to resume a
# failed upload.
def resumable_upload(insert_request):
  response = None
  error = None
  retry = 0
  while response is None:
    try:
      print "Uploading file..."
      status, response = insert_request.next_chunk()
      if 'id' in response:
        print "Video id '%s' was successfully uploaded." % response['id']
      else:
        exit("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" % response)
    except HttpError, e:
      if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
        error = "A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status,
                                                             e.content)
      else:
        raise
    except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS, e:
      error = "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e

    if error is not None:
      print error
      retry += 1
      if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
        exit("No longer attempting to retry.")

      max_sleep = 2 ** retry
      sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
      print "Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying..." % sleep_seconds
      time.sleep(sleep_seconds)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  argparser.add_argument("--file", required=True, help="Video file to upload")
  argparser.add_argument("--title", help="Video title", default="Test Title")
  argparser.add_argument("--description", help="Video description",
    default="Test Description")
  argparser.add_argument("--category", default="22",
    help="Numeric video category. " +
      "See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list")
  argparser.add_argument("--keywords", help="Video keywords, comma separated",
    default="")
  argparser.add_argument("--privacyStatus", choices=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES,
    default=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES[0], help="Video privacy status.")
  args = argparser.parse_args()

  if not os.path.exists(args.file):
    exit("Please specify a valid file using the --file= parameter.")

  youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
  try:
    initialize_upload(youtube, args)
  except HttpError, e:
    print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very useful step-by-step guide about how to get access and fresh tokens and save them for future use using YouTube OAuth API v3. PHP server-side YouTube V3 OAuth API video upload guide.
https://www.domsammut.com/code/php-server-side-youtube-v3-oauth-api-video-upload-guide

Comment: Looks like this is based on a very old version of the API, and it doesn't work any more.

Comment: This is the current version of YouTube API v3 https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Comment: Yes, but there is no info there about how to actually upload from a server (hence this question). I just gave up on it and now tell my customers to just use Vimeo instead.

Answer (score 0):

use "client_secrets.json"

configure credentials to generate it
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

```
{
    "web":
    {
        "client_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "project_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "redirect_uris":["http://localhost:8090/","http://localhost:8090/Callback"],
        "javascript_origins":["http://localhost"]
    }
}
```